# Color change by SKAction?

Tags: sprite, sprite-kit, skaction

I want to change the color of an SKSpriteNode by score.
Its color should change smoothly so I tried to use an SKAction.
But, the color doesn't change.

```
if (score > 20) {

    SKAction *changeColor = [SKAction colorizeWithColor:self.color colorBlendFactor:0 duration:3];

    [self.sprite runAction:changeColor];


    return;
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code? Is the coloring working? The smoothing animation not smooth? Since it's tagged `if-statement`, it doesn't go through your `if`?

Comment: it goes through the if-statement but does not change the color. you mean the code is correct?

Comment: I don't know, but you didn't explicitly said that the color isn't changing. Try to help the ones who can help you by pointing directly what's going wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[SKAction colorizeWithColor:self.color colorBlendFactor:0 duration:3];
```

A `colorBlendFactor` of 0 means that the color takes no effect, ie the color values are multiplied with `colorBlendFactor` to compute the actual amount of color applied to each pixel. Change `colorBlendFactor` to 1 and you'll see the sprite being colorized.